# MVC 4 Json Fails to Encode ViewDataDictionary

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this model assigned to the view:

```
public class PageFormViewModel
{
    public dynamic Form { get; set; }
    public string FormType { get; set; }
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewBags { get; set; }

    public PageFormViewModel()
    {
        ViewBags = new ViewDataDictionary();
    }
}

public class LoadPageViewModel
{
    public Page Page { get; set; }
    public PageFormViewModel PageForm { get; set; }

    public LoadPageViewModel()
    {
        Page = new Page();
        PageForm = new PageFormViewModel();
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in the view, i need to retrieve the model to be sent via Ajax. So i did this in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageForm = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageForm))';
</script>
```

The encoding for Form and FormType is great, but the ViewBags which is ViewDataDictionary type always returns "[]" when I debug it.

Is there a way to encode ViewDataDictionary?

Comment: Why do you have a property that is typeof `ViewDataDictionary`? Its just a `IDictionary<string, object>` so if you don't add any items to it (which you donot appear to be doing), its just an empty array.

Comment: ViewDataDictionary contains Model, ModelState, etc which I needed in some way.

Comment: I think your misunderstanding what the `ViewDataDictionary` is. It a special class containing all the data passed from the controller to the view and its values can be accessed simply using `ViewData[key]`. Having a `ViewDataDictionary` property in your model makes no sense, and its certainly not the same dictionary that the controller passes to the view.

Comment: It is hard to explain here why do I needed it. I am building a CMS right now. The reason why I needed it is because I need to pass ModelState arround the controller - view - controller - view, which cannot be set if I created a new ViewDataDictionary. I think I gave up for now, and just let ViewData[key] that reports the error of form input. ViewDataDictionary is also not serializable, I think using it is not a good thing. Thanks by the way.